# Boot-Repair gets a kernel-panic while scanning the system

Tags: kernel, boot-repair

I had some booting problems after installing Linux to dual boot, so I downloaded the [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) image from Sourceforge, put it onto a USB stick, and tried using it.  I got to an ASCII menu, chose to repair, and it came up with a graphic with five dots in a horizontal row which changed color to indicate activity.  However, after a while it got a kernel panic, with `rtl8821ae_rx_query_desc` appearing to be the kernel function the panic happened in.

Comment: Can you boot using an older kernel? Usually grub offers at least 2 kernel version to boot from

Comment: The Boot-Repair ISO offered on Sourceforge only has one kernel.  If I'd been able to boot off my desktop's hard drive there would have been able to select from various kernel versions, but I couldn't, which was the reason I was using Boot-Repair.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known bug with older versions of the kernel, caused by the driver for the Realtek RTL8821AE WiFi card. Unfortunately, the ISO file which you can download from Sourceforge uses a kernel which is several years old and thus has this bug. Further, that version has no way to get access to the advanced options so as to avoid trying to use the network.

The solution is to download a live Linux distro onto your USB stick, boot into that, install `boot-repair` and invoke it from the command line (the more recent versions of the kernel the live distro use won't have the bug).  Once you get the live distro running and have a terminal, do this (copied from [this howtogeek.com article](http://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/)):

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
boot-repair
```

Comment: I have the same problem as the op and this answer works for me